# AngularJS - How to maintain checked ticket ids of a table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a table containing next & previous pages. I am able to navigate to next/previous pages using next & previous buttons.

On previous & next page actions on call(controller methods) I am pushing checked ticket ids by pushing in an array `$scope.checkedTicketIds`

```
angular.forEach($scope.tickets, function(ticket) {
  if(ticket.checked) {
    $scope.checkedTicketIds.push(ticket.id);
  }
});
```

HTML code is

```
<div class="mail-tools tooltip-demo m-t-md">
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
        <button ng-click="previousPage()" ng-disabled="previousPageBtnDisabled()" class="btn btn-white btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
        <button ng-click="nextPage()" ng-disabled="nextPageBtnDisabled()" class="btn btn-white btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn" dropdown>
            <button ng-disabled="ticketsChecked()" class="btn btn-white dropdown-toggle pull-left" dropdown-toggle type="button">{{'ACTIONS' | translate}} <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left">
                <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in actions"><a ng-click="convertAction(key)">{{key | translate}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In controller on clicking previous page button calling method

```
    $scope.previousPage = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.tickets, function(ticket) {
            if(ticket.checked) {
                $scope.checkedTicketIds.push(ticket.id);
            }
        });

        $scope.ticketsUpdatedQueryCriteria.page = --$scope.page;
                    Tickets.query($scope.ticketsUpdatedQueryCriteria).then(function(tickets) {
                    $scope.tickets = tickets.data;
                    $scope.ticketsPageData = tickets.cursor; 
       });
    };
```

How to pop/remove id on uncheck & I wanted to maintain checked ticket ids for further bulk actions, like change status of one/more tickets. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add a few simplified html code showing your controllers/directives? This will help us to find the best way of helping you (there are plenty of ways to use angular)

Comment: @Deblaton Jean-Philippe I updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implement an example on jsbin, using an independent checked list.

Please, look at:

http://jsbin.com/rudifa/3/

Hope I help you.

Comment: Thanks Joaozito Polo for your answer. This helped me a lot more than an answer.